# School is for learning things

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

A mother asks her son what he learned at school today. Her son responds by reciting this poem:

> Bed holders
>   Leaves at close
>   Keys at Lowes
>   Dies in years
>   Men south are bros (short for "brothers" or slang for "friends")
>   Red folders
>   Peas on toast
>   Fleas on rose

What subject did the son learn about in school today?

Comment: English, but he wasn't paying attention.

Comment: I feel like this has to be a mnemonic but I'm not sure for what. Some of them work for periods one and two on the periodic table but not all of them so

Comment: Poetry maybe? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about this:

> but it has a similar rhyme to
> "Head, Shoulders, Knees and Toes, Knees and Toes" 
> which is a common exercise tune for children.

So my guess would be

> P.E.

Comment: Is there any further explanation to the riddle, or simply that it has similar rhythm to a children's song?

Comment: The rhyme is commonly used for doing a set of exercises where you go faster and faster. It is a good routine for children to exercise and also quickly go over their body parts as well through the words of the song (usually done with those younger).

Comment: Yea I get that, but why didn't the child simply sing the actual song then? Why all the word changes?

Comment: I am guessing to make it a little harder or more of a puzzle, and children are known to come up with their own versions of things (Ever played telephone?)